# What is meant by a "portable" Tex Live installation?

Tags: texlive

Using the Tex Live installer, I can do a *regular* installation and a *portable* installation. In either scenario, I can choose the directories to install into. So, what is actually the difference in the installed system and in its usage?

Comment: Portable = One that can be installed for instance on a flash disk so that you can use it at moreorless any computer.

Comment: @yo' And in a regular installation I can't? What's the difference?

Comment: The regular installation puts some configuration and other similar files in system folders, so they are not in the directory to which you install.

Answer (score 8):

Portable does make a few changes:

- (win32) no creation of menu items and shortcuts and uninstaller
- (unix) no linking of executables/man/info pages to system directories

But the biggest difference is the locations of files and setup of TEXMF variables, namely that everything, absolutely everything is located in the same directory: In particular what happens is that

- `TEXMFHOME` is mapped into `TEXMFLOCAL`
- `TEXMFVAR` is mapped into `TEXMFSYSVAR`
- `TEXMFCONFIG` is mapped into `TEXMFSYSCONFIG`

That means, if you have installed onto your USB stick into `STICK/texlive/2015`, then all files generated, changed, searched are under this directory, which means that there is no configuration in you home directory.

Comment: I created a portable installation that was mounted at `/mnt` at the time of creation. The "portable" installation was created with absolute symbolic links which makes me suspect that the portable installation expects to run from `/mnt`. That doesn't seem very portable to me.

Comment: Of course, if you create links then it is not portable. But the whole point is that you can carry the stick somewhere else and add the binary directory from the usb stick to the path and be set.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the notes in the accepted answer, I wanted also to note this: Here is a comparison I ran in `meld` for the changes in directories between non-portable (left) and portable (right) of [TexLive 2015 install-tl-unx.tar.gz](ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2015/tlnet-final/install-tl-unx.tar.gz):

[image: meld-texlive]

So, as I used `TEXLIVE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/media/mymount/texlive ./install-tl-20160405/install-tl --repository=ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2015/tlnet-final --force-arch=i386-linux` (tried on Ubuntu 14):

- The non-portable installation would end up in a folder `/media/mymount/texlive/2015`
- The portable installation would end up in a folder `/media/mymount/texlive` - without a year subfolder

So, if I still wanted to use a year in the folder name, even with a portable install, I'd have to change my `TEXLIVE_INSTALL_PREFIX` ...